# jquery table selector with condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

i had a table that submitted from my jquery append  script, are its possible to find the match value with jquery selectors, 
i want to check if the condition >= var $minimumEducation, it will pass to next page when submit, i set the value 0 for High School, 1 for Diploma and so on as it use selectbox, the var $minimumEducation variable come from my php admin, anyone knows how to pass this condition ? thanks

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Relation</th>
        <th>DOB</td>
        <th>Education</th>
        <th>Job</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Uncle</td>
        <td>02/19/1955</td>
        <td>Bachelor</td>
        <td>Carpenter</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Amy</td>
        <td>Aunty</td>
        <td>02/19/1950</td>
        <td>Master</td>
        <td>Housewife</td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Eddie</td>
        <td>Cousin</td>
        <td>02/19/1990</td>
        <td>Diploma</td>
        <td>Editor</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Just use $('#familyRelationTabel tr').eq($minimumEducation) @matt-wilson

Answer (score 0):

You can select each matched  element using the :has selector. To match against minimum education you must build the selector string based on the array mapping the education strings to the $minimumEducation value

```
$( "tr:has(td[value="bachelor"], td[value="master"])" )
```

This can be generated similar to the following

```
var query = "";
for (var i = minimumEducation; i < eduarray.length; i++) {
  query += ', td[value="'+eduarray[i]+'"]';
}
query = query.substring(1);
```

Then just put the query string inside the selector

```
$( "tr:has("+query+")" )
```